# Delphi Chromium CEF4 Response Filter

Tags: delphi, chromium, tchromium

Hi fellow stackoverflow,

I have tinkering around delhi CEF4, REsponse filter, and try to catch load resource json responses. with the demo included [here](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi/tree/master/demos/Delphi_VCL/ResponseFilterBrowser):

But the problem looks like it can only triggered once.

Is there anyway to make it triggered again and again. or everytime without reload the page?

```
    procedure TResponseFilterBrowserFrm.Filter_OnFilter(Sender: TObject;
  data_in: Pointer; data_in_size: NativeUInt; var data_in_read: NativeUInt;
  data_out: Pointer; data_out_size: NativeUInt;
  var data_out_written: NativeUInt; var aResult: TCefResponseFilterStatus);
```

I dont understand how this got triggered.

I tried to modify:

```
function TResponseFilterBrowserFrm.IsMyResource(const aRequest
  : ICefRequest): Boolean;
var
  TempName: string;
begin

  Result := True;

end;
```

but it seems it can olny be trigered once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to add FRscCompleted := False;
at the end of this procedure.

procedure TResponseFilterBrowserFrm.StreamCopyCompleteMsg
(var aMessage: TMessage);